# Effects of changing pipe size on a water pressure regulator?

Tags: water, water-pressure, irrigation

I am a biologist and am planning a research experiment. I need to control the water pressure into a drip irrigation system. The water supply is at ~60 psi through a 3/4 pipe. The irrigation emitter I will use operates best at 40 psi. I have found a combo filter and 40 psi pressure regulator but it is a 1" pipe on the inlet and outlet. If I go from 3/4" inlet to the 1" regulator down to a 3/4" outlet will the regulator still deliver 40 psi? Assume that changing the pipe diameters is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An active regulator mechanism is going to go for the target pressure no matter what the pipe size is.

The only way pipe size will enter the picture is if you're flowing so much water that the input pressure is below  target pressure and the regulator can't function.  In that case a smaller pipe on the outlet is a win.